# Code to form a nxn matrix with oeis sequence A072567

Tags: c++, matrix, oeis

i need to code in c++ to form a nxn matrix where 100 <= n <= 1000 with oeis A072567 sequence. This mean wherever i place '1' it should not form a rectangle. the rest places can be filled with 0

here is 21x21 matrix with 105 objects

```
000000000000000011111
010001000100010000001
000100010001000100001
001000100010001000001
000011110000000010000
010010000001001001000
000110000010010000100
001010000100000100010
000000000000111110000
010000010010100000010
000100100100100001000
001001000001100000100
000000001111000010000
010000101000000100100
000101001000001000010
001000011000010001000
100010001000100000001
100001000010000101000
100000100001010000010
100000010100001000100
111100000000000010000
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a free coding service. You must show what you've tried and where you're stuck

Comment: i just need an approach as i can't find any pattern in it